# ios UITableView editing mode checkmark and circle svgs

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, assets

I can't do what I want with the built-in edit mode for a certain table, but I use it for other tables in my app, so I'd like to setup the selected cell in a custom way with the same checkmark and empty circle icons that Apple Uses:

[image: Checkmark Screenshot]
[image: Checkmark Empty Screenshot]

Does anyone know how to get any of:

1. The svg icons for these?
2. The 1x, 2x, 3x icons for these?
3. Another way to reference & use Apple's Foundation Image Assets without adding them to my project directly?

Thanks for any help or direction!

Answer (score 0):

Bingo. New iOS 13 beta came out with new design resources for developers. SF Symbols:

https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/